# Changing background of ImageView is slow

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I am creating an app where I change the background image every time a new quote gets displayed.
I am using ImageView and those pictures are all jpg-files. They are stored in the mipmap folder under xxhdpi, because the images are too big for the drawable folder.

However when I am setting the new ImageView using:

```
background.setBackgroundResource(backgrounds.get(counter));
```

the new picture will be displayed, but it has a delay of half a second. Thats not really cool and I just want to set the new pictues smoothly.

I dont think its useful to post the whole code. The most important parts:

The references are stored in an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> backgrounds;
```

Right after onCreate() I am filling the list like this:

```
backgrounds = new ArrayList<>();
backgrounds.add((Integer) R.mipmap.background1);
backgrounds.add((Integer) R.mipmap.background2);
backgrounds.add((Integer) R.mipmap.background3);
backgrounds.add((Integer) R.mipmap.background4);
```

The pictures have a size between 100KB and 7MB.

Can anyone tell me why the loading is slow and how to improve it? Also, is it right to put those in the xxhdpi folder under mipmap?

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: A 7MB jpeg must have a huge resolution. 1920x1080 is generally enough for all devices, you don't need 4K. You could provide multiple resolutions, and load a smaller one first, then show the larger one when it's done loading. Most likely the delay is due to the image being loaded to memory. However I suggest that you use a library like Glide or Picasso which handles that for you.

Comment: implementation https://github.com/square/picasso and https://github.com/bumptech/glide Your problem will be solved

Comment: I am using picasso now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some valid comments under your question, but I'll add mine as an answer :)

1. Decreasing image sizes are crucial - using JPG instead of PNG and decreasing resolution will save you some time and device battery.
2. Try placing those images under the `drawable-nodpi` folder - this will save you from unneeded image scaling. I presume that you only have one instance of the background in your app.

There is not too much you can do to improve the background setting speed, especially when the images are already baked inside your APK.

Comment: Images are already jpg. I put them all in drawable/nodpi, but same result. Still, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is working properly now. The images were way too big and I reduced the size of them from 2-3MB to ~25KB. They still look good and load properly.